# Cannot fine-tune L2-regularization parameter

Tags: regularization

I have a data set of 1600 examples. I am using 1280 (80%) for training, 160 (10%) for testing, and 160 (10%) for validation. The training goes one of two ways no matter how I fine-tune the L2 parameter:

1) The validation and training error converge, albeit around 75% error

2) The training error settles to around 0%, but the validation error stays around 75%

I don't think my network is too large either. I have trained networks with two hidden layers, both with the same number of nodes as the input. I also tried dropout layers and that did not seem to help.

Does this just mean that I need to add more training examples? Or how do I know that I have reached the limitations of what I am having the network learn?

Comment: How was the validation data selected, randomly or hand selected. I don;t think L2 has anything to do with the problem. Try running the network without L2 and see what the results are.

Comment: It was selected randomly. I have also tried without a validation set and the training set error is very low while the testing set error is very high

Comment: Seems the issue is more complex. Can't give further help without seeing the code.

Comment: Acutally I am able to get 100% accuracy on the training set and 33% on the testing set with a very small network. Hope you are familiar with Mathematica.

func = "ReLU";
net = NetChain[{LinearLayer[in, "Input" -> 50], ElementwiseLayer[func],
   LinearLayer[l4, "Input" -> 50], ElementwiseLayer[func],
   SoftmaxLayer["Input" -> 4]}]